# Android : Log messages in ddms are printing multiple times?

Tags: android, logging, ddms

In my application , on clicking button , downloading some content from  web server in async task. Every thing fine but when i observe DDMS , found that log messages  are repeating for multiple times.Is it problem of DDMS or multiple processes are running in background.

If it was my problem , How to fgure out how many processes are running in background ?

```
05-09 16:37:39.673: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE: Size - 4
05-09 16:37:39.673: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE: Size - 4
05-09 16:37:39.673: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE: Size - 4
05-09 16:37:39.673: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE: Size - 4
05-09 16:37:39.692: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE.1.zip
05-09 16:37:39.692: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE.1.zip
05-09 16:37:39.692: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE.1.zip
05-09 16:37:39.692: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE.1.zip
05-09 16:38:38.933: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DEAfter Compress
05-09 16:38:38.933: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DEAfter Compress
05-09 16:38:38.933: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DEAfter Compress
05-09 16:38:38.933: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DEAfter Compress
05-09 16:38:39.004: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE.2.zip
05-09 16:38:39.004: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE.2.zip
05-09 16:38:39.004: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE.2.zip
05-09 16:38:39.004: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DE.2.zip
05-09 16:38:52.493: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): XX: Size - 4
05-09 16:38:52.493: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): XX: Size - 4
05-09 16:38:52.493: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): XX: Size - 4
05-09 16:38:52.493: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): XX: Size - 4
05-09 16:38:52.557: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): XX.1.zip
05-09 16:38:52.557: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): XX.1.zip
05-09 16:38:52.557: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): XX.1.zip
05-09 16:38:52.557: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): XX.1.zip
05-09 16:39:53.844: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DEAfter Compress
05-09 16:39:53.844: VERBOSE/DownloadManager(12184): DEAfter Compress
```

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a copy and paste from the eclipse logcat screen? If so, the simple fix is to restart eclipse. The log messages will then correctly display on their own.

Your process is only running once, it is an issue with the actual logging. This happens when you restart the application some times.

Comment: yeah i copied from eclipse logcat.

Comment: that should be your problem then. restart eclipse you should see the logs are now singular

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your phone/emulator with adb, then run "ps -A" for a list of processes

Comment: i mean background processess(AsyncTask). I did what u say, but am getting only one processes.